# Angular Grouping Directive starting point

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I'am trying to create a grouping and filtering mechanism with several predefined filters. I have a collection of undefined rules and some predefined grouping actions, for example "relativeDate" (today, tomorrow, yesterday, this week, ...), "boolean" or . The set of actions should be expandable.

I've managed to get this working in a controller. But I want to outsource this into a directive to get this working with other object collections. The Problem is: I need to specify the template of the list dynamically.

Imagine the following collections:

```
$scope.memosReceived = [
     { id: 1, from: 'Henry Ford', title: 'Want your Model T?', received: '2015-05-04T12:30:00', read: true },
     { id: 2, from: 'Oliver Newton', title: 'Look at this!', received: '2015-06-15T08:00:00', read: true }
     ...
];

$scope.memosSent = [
     { id: 1, to: 'Henry Ford', title: 'That is an old car', sent: '2015-05-04T12:35:21', read: true },
     { id: 2, to: 'Oliver Newton', title: 'Stop Spam', sent: '2015-06-15T08:01:47', read: false }
     ...
];
```

Now the markup should be like the following:

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <h2>Received</h2>
    <grouped-list ng-model="memosReceived" item-var="received" grouping-options="groupingReceived">
        <h2>{{ received.title }} <sub>by {{ received.from }}</h2>
    </grouped-list>

    <h2>Sent</h2>
    <grouped-list ng-model="memosSent" item-var="sent" grouping-options="groupingSent">
        <h2>{{ sent.title }} <sub>to {{ sent.to }}</h2>
    </grouped-list>
</div>
```

Options could be like:

```
$scope.groupingReceived = [
    { modelKey: 'received', action: 'relativeDate', options: { [.. passed to grouping action, like value->name mapping ..] },
    { modelKey: 'read', action: 'boolean', options: { [...] } }];

$scope.groupingSent = [
    { modelKey: 'sent', action: 'relativeDate', options: { [.. passed to grouping action, like value->name mapping ..] },
    { modelKey: 'read', action: 'boolean', options: { [...] } }];
```

The rendered HTML should look like this "PseudoHtml":

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <h2>Received</h2>
    <div class="grouped-list">
        <div class="filter-section">
            <button ng-click="openFilters = !openFilters>Open Filters</button>
            <div class="filter-options" ng-hide="!openFilters">
                <h4>Group by</h4>
                [selectbox given group actions] [selectbox sort ascending or descending]
                <h4>Filter by</h4>
                [build filters by similar to group actions given filter actions]
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="group-header">
                <h3>Yesterday</h3>
            </div>
            <ul class="group-list">
                <li ng-repeat="received in ngModel | customFilters">
                    <!-- something like transclusion starts here -->
                    <h2>{{ received.title }} <sub>by {{ received.from }}</h2>
                    <!-- something like transclusion ends here -->            
                </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="group-header">
                <h3>Last Week</h3>
            </div>
            <ul class="group-list">
                <li ng-repeat="received in ngModel | customFilters">
                    <!-- something like transclusion starts here -->
                    <h2>{{ received.title }} <sub>by {{ received.from }}</h2>
                    <!-- something like transclusion ends here -->            
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2>Sent</h2>
    <div class="grouped-list">
        [... same like above ...]
    </div>
</div>
```

I am really struggeling how to achieve this behavior, where to store the several parts of the logic (e.g. the grouping actions, the custom filters) and how to transclude this correctly.

Maybe someone can give me a good starting point for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom filter and call it from the controller of your directive.

Inside of this filter you can decide which filter action should be triggered by passing parameters to the filter.

I would call it from the controller instead of the template because there you can easier chain your filters.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/y5eppsw6/).

During adding my code to SO I've detected a bug (not displaying the item) in my code with a newer AngularJS version. Not sure what it is but with 1.2.1 it's working.
I'll check this later. Seems like a scoping issue.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .filter('aw-group', function($filter) {
        var filterMethods = {
            relativeDate: function(input, action) {
                console.log('relative date called', input);
                return input; // do the translation to relative date here
            },
            filterByNumber: function(input, action, options) {
                // if you need mor parameters
                return $filter('filter')(input, options.number);
            },
           otherFilter: {
           }
        };
        
        return function(input, action, options) {
            return filterMethods[action](input, action, options);
        };
    })   
    .directive('groupedList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            itemVar: '=',
            filter: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in filteredModel" ng-transclude>'+
        '</li></ul>',
        controller: function($scope, $filter) {
            //console.log($scope.filter);
            
            $scope.filteredModel = $filter('aw-group')($scope.model, 'filterByNumber', { number: 2 }); // passing action from $scope.filter.action as second parameter, third is an options object
        }
    };
})
    .controller('mainController', function () {
    this.data = [{
        title: 'Test1',
        from: 'tester1'
    }, {
        title: 'Test2',
        from: 'tester1'
    }, {
        title: 'Test3',
        from: 'tester1'
    }, ];
    this.groupingReceived = [{
        modelKey: 'received',
        action: 'relativeDate',
        options: {},
        modelKey: 'read',
        action: 'boolean',
        options: {}
    }];

    this.memosReceived = [{
        id: 1,
        from: 'Henry Ford',
        title: 'Want your Model T?',
        received: '2015-05-04T12:30:00',
        read: true
    }, {
        id: 2,
        from: 'Oliver Newton',
        title: 'Look at this!',
        received: '2015-06-15T08:00:00',
        read: true
    }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
    <grouped-list model="ctrl.data" item-var="received" filter="ctrl.groupingReceived">
         <h2>{{item.title}}<sub>{{item.from}}</sub></h2>

    </grouped-list>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the problem. ng-transclude isn't working with ng-repeat in newer versions. I've tried the same thing.

Comment: OK, thanks for pointing at that issue. I've updated the same jsFiddle. Please have a look. It's working now.  If I've undestood correctly the new directive is injecting the `ng-repeat` scope into the transclusion scope.  I've took the code from a plunkr from [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874) discussion about that problem.